# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, windows-forms, mariadb

Estoy tratando de guardar un `datetime` en una base de datos sin usar `string` ya que esa es la consigna pero me sale esto... el codigo es :

```
MySqlConnection miConexion = Conexion.getConexion();
        string sql = "";
        string auxdate2 = auxdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        sql = "UPDATE turnos set fecha = '"+ Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text)+"' , hora = '"+ txtHora.Text + "' , tiempoEstimado = '"+ txtEstimado.Text+ 
            "' , tipoLavado = '"+ txtTipoLavado.Text+ "' , descripcion = '"+ txtDescripcion.Text+ "' , monto = '"+ txtMonto.Text +"' where patente = '" +comboPatente.Text +" and fecha = '"+ auxdate2 + "' ;";
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, miConexion);
         miConexion.Open();
        int tuplas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery(); // ACA VA EL ERROR
```

El código de error es el siguiente:

```
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2022-02-23'' at line 1'`
```

La verdad no sé que pueda estar fallando espero me puedan ayudar, mi programa funciona con un `datagrid` y una función para agregar turnos y esa funciona correctamente, la que me está dando errores es la de modificar los turnos.

La funcion de agregar turnos es la siguiente:

```
            sql = "INSERT INTO turnos (fecha, hora, patente, tiempoEstimado, tipoLavado, descripcion, monto)" + " VALUES(@Fecha, @Hora, @Patente, @Estimado, @Tipolavado, @Descripcion, @Monto)";
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, miConexion);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", turno.Fecha);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patente", turno.Patente);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", turno.Hora);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estimado", turno.Estimado);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipolavado", turno.Tipolavado);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monto", turno.Monto);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", turno.Descripcion);
            int tuplas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: te falta una comilla simple... siempre, verifica como queda el comando... lo que no entiendo es porque no haces lo mismo en el update que en insert, porque no usas parametros, que justamente ayudan a que no te pase lo que pasa!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Te falta una comilla simple al generar tu consulta, debería quedar así tu código:

```
sql = "UPDATE turnos set fecha = '"+ 
Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text)+"' , hora = '"+ 
txtHora.Text + "' , tiempoEstimado = '"+ txtEstimado.Text+ 
        "' , tipoLavado = '"+ txtTipoLavado.Text+ "' , descripcion 
= '"+ txtDescripcion.Text+ "' , monto = '"+ txtMonto.Text +"' where 
patente = '" +comboPatente.Text + '" and fecha = '"+ auxdate2 + "' 
;";
```